# Naming a POJO variable "public"

Tags: java, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I am working with MongoDB and have a hard requirement to use the MongoDB Java Driver (v.3.0.2) I also can not change the structure of the database in any way.

One of the documents in the db holds a field with a name of "public" which is a POJO.

Retrieval of the documents for display is trivial because I'm just casting the BSON document collection to JSON directly. However, on a PUT/POST, changing this attribute to something other than the name "public" will cause the schema to change, which is not allowed.

I am planning at this point to rename the field in the POJO but that means having to manually hydrate the object in the POST/PUT and also manually build the BSON document to get the naming right.

Just wanted to see if someone has run into a similar issue and if there are any suggestions to easily get around this, without using an extraneous mapping framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I utilized a combination of JAX XMLElement tags and the GSON SerializedName tags like such:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class _Document {
    @XmlElement(name="public")
    @SerializedName("public")
    private String _public;
    ...
```

Any other suggestions?